# How to display a windows alert near my link

Tags: javascript

hello For the moment my code displays an alert when I click on "envoyer une alerte"

But the alert is displayed far from the "envoyer une alerte" link

I would like the alert to be displayed near the link display an alert

I have to modify what in my code so that the alert is glued to my link

https://codepen.io/Wilou/pen/eNNEme

```
<alert>
  <div id="overlay" ></div>
  <div id="alertPanel" ></div>
</alert>

<a href="#" onclick="alert('Alerte Personnalisé','contenue de cette alerte');">send an alert</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Alerte Personnalisé numéro 2','contenue de cette alerte number 2');">send an alert</a>
```

```
alert #overlay{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.7;
  display: none;
}
alert #alertPanel{
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  min-height: 170px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 24%;
  z-index:9999;
  color:#000;
  border:1px solid #303030;
  background-color:#eaeaea;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight:100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
alert div.texte{
  width: 400px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
alert span.close{
  background: url('') no-repeat center center;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:32px;
  width:32px;
  position:absolute;
  right:12px;
  top:12px;
  cursor:pointer;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  opacity:1.0;
}

alert #alertPanel h2{
  font-weight:100%;
  font-size:22px;
  padding:25px 0px 15px 15px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  margin:0px;
  background-color: #323232;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```
window.alert = function(titre, message) {
    document.getElementById("alertPanel").innerHTML = "<span class=\"close\" onclick=\"closealert();\"></span><h2>" + titre + "</h2><div class=\"texte\">" + message + "</div>";
    document.getElementById('alertPanel').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block';
}
function closealert()
{
    document.getElementById('alertPanel').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite the built-in `alert()`? There's no such thing as `<alert>` in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the clicked element as argument in the onclick handler.

Then, use the element to determine its position using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and apply it to your `alertPanel`.

```js
window.alert = function(link, titre, message) {
  
  // Store this in a variable instead of querying the document multiple times
  let alertPanel = document.getElementById("alertPanel")
  alertPanel.innerHTML = "<span class=\"close\" onclick=\"closealert();\"></span><h2>" + titre + "</h2><div class=\"texte\">" + message + "</div>";
  alertPanel.style.display = 'block';
  
  // Get the position of the clicked link
  let position = link.getBoundingClientRect()
  
  // Apply the position to the alertPanel
  alertPanel.style.top = position.top + 20 + "px";
  alertPanel.style.left = position.left + "px";
  
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function closealert() {
  document.getElementById('alertPanel').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
alert #overlay{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.7;
  display: none;
}
alert #alertPanel{
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  min-height: 170px;
  width: 450px;
  /*margin-left: 24%;*/
  z-index:9999;
  color:#000;
  border:1px solid #303030;
  background-color:#eaeaea;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight:100%;
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
}
alert div.texte{
  width: 400px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
alert span.close{
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat center center;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:32px;
  width:32px;
  position:absolute;
  right:12px;
  top:12px;
  cursor:pointer;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  opacity:1.0;
}

alert #alertPanel h2{
  font-weight:100%;
  font-size:22px;
  padding:25px 0px 15px 15px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  margin:0px;
  background-color: #323232;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<alert>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="alertPanel"></div>
</alert>

<a href="#" onclick="alert(this,'Alerte Personnalisé','contenue de cette alerte');">send an alert</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="alert(this,'Alerte Personnalisé numéro 2','contenue de cette alerte number 2');">send an alert</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but I can no longer close the pop up alert

Comment: I edited with the CSS from your codepen. Notice that I removed the `margin-left` and `margin-bottom` from `alert #alertPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `alert` element to `position: relative`, and align position of `alertPanel` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer you are talking about alert #overlay  position:relative

Comment: Not exactly. Set `position: relative` to your custom `alert` tag.
In your CSS: `alert{
 position: relative;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can modified the position in this class: `alert #alertPanel`

In the example below i change the `top` and `margin-left` property.

```css
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 300px;
```

```js
window.alert = function(titre, message) {
    document.getElementById("alertPanel").innerHTML = "<span class=\"close\" onclick=\"closealert();\"></span><h2>" + titre + "</h2><div class=\"texte\">" + message + "</div>";
    document.getElementById('alertPanel').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block';
}
function closealert()
{
    document.getElementById('alertPanel').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
alert #overlay{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.7;
  display: none;
}
alert #alertPanel{
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  min-height: 170px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 250px;;
  z-index:9999;
  color:#000;
  border:1px solid #303030;
  background-color:#eaeaea;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight:100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
alert div.texte{
  width: 400px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
alert span.close{
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAABGdBTUEAANjr9RwUqgAAACBjSFJNAABtmAAAc44AAPJxAACDbAAAg7sAANTIAAAx7AAAGbyeiMU/AAAG7ElEQVR42mJkwA8YoZjBwcGB6fPnz4w/fvxg/PnzJ2N6ejoLFxcX47Rp036B5Dk4OP7z8vL+P3DgwD+o3v9QjBUABBALHguZoJhZXV2dVUNDgxNIcwEtZnn27Nl/ZmZmQRYWFmag5c90dHQY5OXl/z98+PDn1atXv79+/foPUN9fIP4HxRgOAAggRhyWMoOwqKgoq6GhIZe3t7eYrq6uHBDb8/Pz27Gysloga/jz588FYGicPn/+/OapU6deOnXq1GdgqPwCOuA31AF/0S0HCCB0xAQNBU4FBQWB0NBQublz59oADV37Hw28ePHi74MHD/6ii3/8+HEFMGQUgQ6WEhQU5AeZBTWTCdkigABC9ylIAZeMjIxQTEyMysaNG/3+/v37AGTgr1+//s2cOfOXm5vbN6Caz8jY1NT0a29v76/v37//g6q9sHfv3khjY2M5YAgJgsyEmg0PYYAAQreUk4+PT8jd3V1l1apVgUAzfoIM2rlz5x9gHH5BtxAdA9PB1zNnzvyB+R6oLxoopgC1nBPZcoAAgiFQnLIDMb+enp5iV1eXBzDeHoI0z58//xcwIX0mZCkMg9S2trb+hFk+ffr0QCkpKVmQ2VA7QHYxAgQQzLesQMwjIiIilZWVZfPu3bstMJ+SYikyBmUzkBnA9HEMyNcCYgmQHVC7mAACCJagOEBBbGdnp7lgwYJEkIavX7/+BcY1SvAaGRl9tba2xohjMTGxL8nJyT+AWQsuxsbG9vnp06e/QWYdPHiwHmiWKlBcCGQXyNcAAQSzmBuoSQqYim3u37+/EKR48uTJv5ANB+bVr7Dga2xs/AkTV1JS+gq0AJyoQIkPWU9aWtoPkPibN2/2A/l6QCwJ9TULQADB4hcY//xKXl5eHt++fbsAUmxhYYHiM1DiAsr9R7ZcVVUVbikIdHd3/0TWIyws/AWYVsByAgICdkAxRSAWAGI2gACClV7C4uLiOv7+/lEgRZ8+ffqLLd6ABck3ZMuB6uCWrlu37je29HDx4kVwQisvL88FFqkaQDERUHADBBAomBl5eHiYgQmLE1hSgQQZgIUD1lJm69atf4HR8R1YKoH5QIPAWWP9+vV/gOI/gHkeQw+wGAXTwAJJ5t+/f/BUDRBA4NIEKMDMyMjICtQIiniG379/4yza7t69+//Lly8oDrty5co/bJaCAEwcZCkwwTJDLWYCCCCwxcDgY3z16hXDnTt3voP4EhISWA0BFgZMwNqHExh3jMiG1tbWsgHjnA2bHmAeBtdWwOL1MycnJ7wAAQggBmi+kgIW/OaKiorJwOLuFShO0LMSMPF9AUYBSpz6+vqixHlOTs4P9MIEWHaDsxSwYMoE2mEGFJcG5SKAAGJCqjv/AbPUn8ePH98ACQQHB6NUmZqamkzABIgSp5s3bwbHORCA1QDLAWZkPc7OzszA8oHl5cuXVy5duvQBGIXwWgoggGA+FgO6xkBNTS28r69vDrT2+Y1cIMDyJchX6KkXVEmAshd6KB06dAic94EO3AzkBwGxPhCLg8ptgACCZyeQp9jZ2b2AmsuAefM8tnxJCk5ISPgOLTKfAdNEOVDMA2QHLDsBBBC8AAFlbmCLwlZISCg5JSVlJizeQAaQaimoWAUFK0g/sGGwHiiWCMS2yAUIQAAxI7c4gEmeFZi4OJ48ecLMzc39CRiEmgEBASxA/QzA8vYvAxEgNjaWZc2aNezAsprp2LFjp4FpZRdQ+AkQvwLij0AMSoC/AQIIXklAC3AVUBoBxmE8sPXQAiyvN8J8fuPGjR/h4eHf0eMdhkENhOPHj8OT+NGjR88BxZuBOA5kJtRseCUBEECMSI0AdmgBDooDaaDl8sASTSkyMlKzpqZGU1paGlS7MABLrX83b978A6zwwakTmE0YgIkSnHpBfGCV+gxYh98qKSk5CeTeAxVeQPwUiN8AMSjxgdLNX4AAYkRqCLBAXcMHtVwSaLkMMMHJAvOq9IQJE9R8fHxElJWV1bEF8aNHj+7t27fvLTDlXwXGLyhoH0OD+DnU0k/QYAa1QP8BBBAjWsuSFWo5LzRYxKFYAljqiAHzqxCwIBEwMTERBdZeoOYMA7Bl+RFYEbwB5oS3IA9D4/IFEL+E4nfQ6IDFLTgvAwQQI5ZmLRtSsINSuyA0uwlBUyQPMPWD20/AKo8ByP4DTJTfgRgUjB+gFoEc8R6amGDB+wu5mQsQQIxYmrdMUJ+zQTM6NzQEeKGO4UJqOzFADQMZ/A1qCSzBfQXi71ALfyM17sEAIIAY8fQiWKAYFgIwzIbWTv4HjbdfUAf8RPLhH1icojfoAQKIEU8bG9kRyF0aRiz6YP0k5C4LsmUY9TtAADEyEA+IVfufGEUAAQYABejinPr4dLEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') no-repeat center center;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:32px;
  width:32px;
  position:absolute;
  right:12px;
  top:12px;
  cursor:pointer;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  opacity:1.0;
}

alert #alertPanel h2{
  font-weight:100%;
  font-size:22px;
  padding:25px 0px 15px 15px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  margin:0px;
  background-color: #323232;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<alert>
  <div id="overlay" ></div>
  <div id="alertPanel" ></div>
</alert>

<a href="#" onclick="alert('Alerte Personnalisé','contenue de cette alerte');">Envoyer une alerte</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Alerte Personnalisé numéro 2','contenue de cette alerte number 2');">En envoyer une autre</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but that does not matter the pop up is positioned far from the link

Comment: @phil2202 But you know that you can change `  top: 10px;`and `margin-left: 300px;` by your own. If you want more to the link the reduce margin-left. Maybe to 200px